# Can I compare the inequality between mean of inverse sigmoid and inverse sigmoid of mean?

Tags: probability, statistics, inequality, vectors, means

I have vectors $x_i$ which obtained by the sigmoid function,
$$ \{x_1, x_2, \cdots , x_n \}, x_i \in (0,1) $$
and I can get inverse sigmoid of $x_i$, such that $z_i = - \ln (\frac{1}{x_i} -1 ) $ .

What I'm cursious about is, let $\bar{x}$ is the mean of $x_i$ and $\bar{z}$ is the mean of $z_i$,

Are $\bar{z}$ and the inverse sigmoid of $\bar{x}$ the same?

To clarify, I'd like to ask $\bar{z}= \frac{1}{n}\sum_i^n (- \ln( \frac{1}{x_i } -1)) = -  \ln (\frac{1}{\bar{x}}-1)$ ?
If not, how about the inequality between them?

Comment: no to equality.. take $n=2$ and try it out. For example, take $x_1 = 0.1, x_2 = 0.2$

Comment: Then, can I get a upper/lower bound of the mean of the inverse sigmoid? I'm trying to prove their inequality, but nothing pops up my head